# x = (a) => b(a) is not the same thing as `x = b`

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

`const x = (a) => b(a)` is the same thing as `const x = b`

```js
const a = () => { console.log('hi'); }
let x1 = a;
let x2 = () => a();

x1();
x2();
```

---

Whats the difference between..

```
const equalField = R.propEq('field'); // NOT WORK!
```

and

```
const equalField = (f) => R.propEq('field')(f); // WORKS!
```

The first one **return a function**, the second one **return the result**.

Check my code snippet...

```js
const addingError = {
  message: '',
  errors: [ { field: "number" }, { field: "mac" } ]
}

// const equalField = R.propEq('field'); // NOT WORK!
const equalField = (f) => R.propEq('field')(f); // WORKS!

const getErrors = R.pipe(R.always(addingError), R.prop('errors'))
const anyField = R.converge(R.any, [equalField, getErrors])
const result = anyField('mac');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

### My intention is...

When I call `anyField('mac')`

`R.any` will be called with `R.any(equalField('mac'), getErrors('mac'))`

1. `equalField('mac')` returns a function, and this is ok because the first argument of `R.any` is a function
2. `getErrors('mac')` returns a array, and this is ok because the second argument of `R.any` is an array.

Comment: @Xufox, `R.propEq` is curry. `R.propEq('a', 'b')` is the same that `R.propEq('a')('b')` as you can see in my question.

Comment: It really depends on what exactly `R.propEq` is and what exactly you mean by “doesn’t work”. You’ve edited your question but now your working lines are inconsistent in the two code samples. Which one really doesn’t work? And how?

Comment: I've never seen the `R.propEq` used like where you say it "NOT WORK" - perhaps that's why it doesn't work, because it's not meant to be used that way

Comment: Also, what do you mean it does "NOT WORK", is there an error? or is it that you're trying to use `equalField` incorrectly perhaps?

Comment: `The first one return a function` yes, it would, of course it would because it does

Comment: I added more details.. not work because return a function instead the actual result

Comment: Ok.. `const x = (a) => b(a)` is not the same as `const x = b` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX, please check my question, I add more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It all depends on `b` …**

> `x = (a) => b(a)` is **not** the same thing as `x = b`

- **You are wrong if** `b` is a function that expects exactly 1 argument – or `b` is a curried function
- **You are right if** `b` is a function that expects more than 1 argument

The problem is compounded because Ramda has a magical API that allows you to interact with a single function as if it was curried *or* uncurried.

```
// Ramda magic
R.propEq('a', 'b', {a: 'b'}) // true
R.propEq('a')('b', {a: 'b'}) // true
R.propEq('a', 'b')({a: 'b'}) // true
R.propEq('a')('b')({a: 'b'}) // true
```

This is going to generate some confusion (and I personally think this sucks), but we're going to ignore it for now

---

**Simplified demonstrations**

Below: `b` is a function that expects exactly 1 argument. `x` and `y` work as intended

```js
const b = n => n + 1
const x = b
const y = n => b (n)

console.log(x(1)) // 2
console.log(y(1)) // 2
```

---

Below: `b` is a function that expects more than 1 argument – `y` is a problem in this case

```js
const b = (n,m) => n + m
const x = b
const y = n => b(n)

console.log(x(1,2)) // 3
console.log(y(1,2)) // NaN
```

---

Below: `b` is a **curried** function that expects more than 1 argument – `y` is no longer a problem

```js
const b = n => m => n + m
const x = b
const y = n => b(n)

console.log(x(1)(2)) // 3
console.log(y(1)(2)) // 3
```

---

**Ramda magic sauce; source of confusion**

So regarding Ramda specifically, the answer is slightly more complicated

Below, if we call `x` and `y` in curried form, we get exactly the answer we are expecting – *however*, if we call `x` and `y` with *both* remaining arguments, then only `x` will perform as expected; `y` will return a function waiting for the last argument

```
const b = R.propEq('a')
const x = b
const y = n => b(n)

// call in curried form, everything works as expected
console.log(x('b')({a: 'b'})) // true
console.log(y('b')({a: 'b'})) // true

// call with both args, y blows up
console.log(x('b', {a: 'b'})) // true
console.log(y('b', {a: 'b'})) // function n(r){return 0===arguments.length||b(r)?n:t.apply(this,arguments)}
```

The error is of course because of the way we defined `y`

```
// bad, only accommodates one extra argument
// ramda super magical api would allow any number of arguments per application
const y = n => b(n)

// instead write
const y = (...args) => b(...args)

// above: which of course is stupid in a whole new way
// instead just write
const y = b

// above which is stupid, too
// instead just write
b
```

---

**Your intention**

I (think) I understand what you're trying to do in your updated post. If so, the following snippet might be of some help to you

```
const fieldEq = R.propEq('field')

const errorsInclude = type => 
  R.compose (R.any(fieldEq(type)), R.prop('errors'))

const addingError = {
  message: '',
  errors: [ { field: "number" }, { field: "mac" } ]
}

errorsInclude('mac') (addingError) // true
errorsInclude('number') (addingError) // true
errorsInclude('foo') (addingError) // false
```

Be careful not to fetishize point-free programming. In the code above, `errorsInclude` *must* be called in curried form. The Ramda Way® might suggest you use `R.curry` for the binary function

```
const errorsInclude = R.curry((type, x) =>
  R.compose (R.any(fieldEq(type)), R.prop('errors')) (x))

// now you can call it either way
console.log(errorsInclude('mac', addingError)) // true
console.log(errorsInclude('mac')(addingError)) // true
```

But! this sorta defeats the purpose of `R.compose` – I personally think the following is probably the best you can end up with if you want to adhere to ramda conventions

```
const errorsInclude = R.curry((type, x) =>
  R.any(fieldEq(type), R.prop('errors', x)))
```

There's nothing sexy about it, but it at least it's straightforward – just my 2 cents.

---

@ScottSauyet comments that it could also be solved using `R.useWith`:

```
const errorsInclude = R.useWith(R.any, [R.propEq('field'), R.prop('errors')]);
```

---

**For what it's worth**

Your question title is at the core of lambda calculus' [eta conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) –

```
const g = x => f (x)  ==  f
      g(y)            ==  f(y)
      g               ==  f
```

This only works as a *law* when **all** functions accept/expect exactly 1 argument tho (which is the case in lambda calculus).

Comment: That's an amazing answer!

Comment: Yep.. I agree. Help-me a lot.

Comment: @zerkms thanks. That means a lot coming from you ^_^

Comment: Absolutely, this is a great answer.  And while I agree that we should not make a fetish of point-free, Ramda does offer [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), designed to allow point-free in such a situation if you choose.  You could use it like this: `const errorsInclude = R.useWith(R.any, [ R.propEq('field'),  R.prop('errors')]);`